# Global Lipschitz continuity of a normalized mixture of Gaussians

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $(w_i)_{i=1}^N$, $(c_i)_{i=1}^N$ and $(\sigma_i)_{i=1}^N$ be real-valued sequences. The function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
f(s)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^Nw_{i}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{i}^{2}}(s-c_{i})^{2}}}{\sum_{i=1}^Ne^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{i}^{2}}(s-c_{i})^{2}}}
$$

is widely used in the context of Dynamic Movement Primitives (DMPs), a method of trajectory control/planning for robots.¹

Some questions regarding the stability of this method depends on the Lipchistz continuity of $f$. In particular, I was wondering the following question:

Is $f$ **globally** Lipschitz continuous for any choice of $N > 1$, $(w_i)_{i=1}^N$, $(c_i)_{i=1}^N$ and $(\sigma_i)_{i=1}^N$?

[1] *Ijspeert, Auke Jan; Nakanishi, Jun; Hoffmann, Heiko; Pastor, Peter; Schaal, Stefan*, [**Dynamical movement primitives: learning attractor models for motor behaviors**](https://doi.org/10.1162/NECO_a_00393), Neural Comput. 25, No. 2, 328-373 (2013). [ZBL1269.92002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1269.92002).